# searching with Ajax on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

What is the simplest way of getting the nth User in a database (`User.find(n)` in rails) using a field (where n is the input) and a button, and displaying it on the page using Ajax?

```
<input id="search_input" type="text">
<button id="search_button">Search</button>
<div id="output> Output displayed here </div>
```

I read the [Ajax tutorial on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) where an XMLHttpRequest object is created, but this seems way too long winded for doing something so simple. Is there an easier way in rails?

This is the Javascript function I would have to call when the button is pressed

```
function find_nth_user() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.rb",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and then in file ajax_info.rb (which has to be routed correctly) have the rails code.

I tried searching for Ajax on Rails but all I find is stuff to do with forms_for which I don't think are applicable here. I need to function to execute on a button press.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be dealing with the barebones objects like this. jQuery/Prototype/Zepto exist so you don't have to do this stuff.

Watch this railscast on searching with AJAX: http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax